# Why other people can't get access to my WampServer in LAN?

Tags: wampserver

I can visit WampServer through localhost 127.0.0.1. 
  And I try to change the Port 80 to other number. Like this "Listen 80" --> "Listen 8080" in httpd.conf. The firewall has been shutdown.
  I am sure I have set the WampServer "Put Online".

Why still can't visit by others in LAN?

Many thanks!

Comment: to be shure that isnt a open port problem, do you telnet lan.ip.address 8080 from another machine?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when trying to vist the site after a port change that you specify the port

localhost:8080 for instance

other wise the browser will assume it is port 80

Hope this helps a little

Comment: @skcheng Fair enough, When you said you shutdown the firewall what OS is this and how did you turn it off? disabling windows firewall will stop users accessing your server you need to go into the options and allow all connections or modify it to allow 8080. so again not sure if this helping at all don't know how much you already know :)